# is there a way to delete some content from a field in mysql?

Tags: mysql

eg: there is a field named `products_description` in table `products`.

```
<p><span class="Apple-style-span">
<p class="f12&quot;">Product Information of<a href="http://www.example.com/1.html">&nbsp;<strong>Pinocchio DVD (Disney)</strong></a></p>
<b>Language:</b>English  <b>Boxed Set:</b>Yes  <b>Discs:</b>2 pcs    <b>Release date:</b>9 February 1940  <b>Condition:</b>New  <b>Weight:</b>0.5kg    <b>Format:</b>Support both NTSC &amp; PAL  <b>No. of Season:</b>    <b>Name
<p class="f12">Main Images<p>
```

the `products_description` table have many  records like the above. now, i want to use some commonds to delete the content begin with`<strong><a href="http://www.example.com/1.html">.....</a></strong>` part. the url may be `http://www.example.com/2.html`... . if the `products_description` has it. thank u.

Comment: Uh... [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) with a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @JaredFarrish he wants to delete only part of the content. DELETE would delete the whole row.

Comment: @user745434 - That would explain why the obvious wasn't so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
update products
set products_description = replace(products_description, '<a href="http://www.example.com/1.html">', '')
```

Comment: thank you, if the url is http://www.example.com/2.html. how should i do. i want to delete the content part which begin with <strong><a href="http://www.example.com/...